# Android : unable to enable bluetooth adapter

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am running an embedded system on android 2.1. The system has a bluetooth chip.
Calling getDefaultAdapter returns an adapter so BT is available
however i'm not able to enable the adapter even when user gives permission.

I also tried using bluetoothadapter.enable() and its still not working.

I've tested the code on a phone and it works,

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Do not use without explicit user action to turn on Bluetooth.

> Bluetooth should never be enabled without direct user consent.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable%28%29).